# Spyder 4.0.0 Editor and pathlib.PurePath converted my editor into random html code

Tags: python, html, spyder

I was working on a coding project in Spyder4.0.0, when I ran one of my cells (ctrl+enter)to print out a path on my console, pathlib.PurePath(root,subdir), my editor turned into html code, that seemingly has the data I wanted on my console, inscribed into my editor.  This is really weird, and I cannot find any other information regarding this issue.

```
'''
!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd">
html><head>
meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
meta name="qrichtext" content="1" /><style type="text/css">
p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }
/style></head><body style=" font-family:'Consolas'; font-size:10pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;">
p style=" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;"> PureWindowsPath('/Documents/Lab/MCU/Outputs/PRJNAXXXXX/SRRXXXXXX/PRJNAXXXXXX/SRRXXXXXX'),</p>
p style=" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;"> PureWindowsPath('/Documents/Lab/MCU/Outputs/PRJNAXXXXX/SRRXXXXXXX/PRJNAXXXXXXX/SRRXXXXX'),</p>
'''
```

All my actual code has been removed and seemingly replaced with this nonsense.
Is my code actually gone?  How did this even happen?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Note:  I deleted a lot of "<"s, so the html code can appear in the stackoverflow thread.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) I'm really sorry for what happened to you in this case and I don't know what could have caused it. The only way for us to get to bottom of this and fix it is for you to give us a reproducible and simple example that generates it again. So if you manage to recover your code and can share it with us, please open an issue about it [here](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues). Other than that, we can't do anything for you, sorry.

Comment: Hi Carlos.  Thanks for replying!  Unfortunately, I have been unable to reproduce the issue.  :(.  I suspect that when I hit ctrl+entr, the mouse was hovering over a word in the editor, which brought up a pop-up, and the ctrl+entr activated on whatever popped up.  I am just unable to figure out what pop-up would've done this.